# When is both a statement and its negation incorrect?

Tags: propositional-calculus

In Chiswell's *Mathematical Logic*, one of the exercises is to show that the following statement admits counterexamples:

> if $\Gamma\vdash(\phi\lor\psi)$ is a correct sequent then at least
>   one of $\Gamma\vdash\phi$ and $\Gamma\vdash\psi$ is also correct.

The hint for this exercise suggests finding examples where both $\vdash p$ and $\vdash(\neg p)$ are not correct sequents.  But even this last part perplexes me, for, given the context, one is expected to give a counterexample from basic mathematics.

My question is: what's a simple example wherein both $\vdash p$ and $\vdash(\neg p)$ are not correct sequents?

Comment: If the language has $P$ as an atom and no axioms, then I would think neither $\vdash P$ nor $\vdash \lnot P$ would be a correct sequent (since in each case there will be an assignment of truth values to atoms making the statement false).

Comment: @DanielSchepler you're right -- fixed!  I must confess I don't quite understand your first comment.

Comment: In terms of Model Theory: If $\Gamma$ is not a complete theory then some sentence $p$ is neither provable nor disprovable from $\Gamma.$  Then  neither $\Gamma \vdash p$ nor $\Gamma \vdash \neg p$ is true. But the law of the Excluded Middle requires  $\Gamma\vdash (p\lor \neg p).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet But what would be a simple example of this?  The textbook uses examples like having $p$ stand for $2=3$, and other simple sentences.  That's what has me stuck.

Comment: Let $\Gamma$ be the axioms for a group. Let $p$ be $\forall x,y\;(xy=yx).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See : [Chiswell and Hodges, page 7](https://books.google.it/books?id=c4QSDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA7) :

> We read the sequent $(Γ \vdash ψ)$ as "$Γ$ entails $ψ$". The sequent means
>
> > There is a proof whose conclusion is $ψ$ and whose undischarged assumptions are all in the set $Γ$.
>
> When it is true, we say that the sequent is *correct*. The set $Γ$ can be empty, in which case we write $(\vdash ψ)$; this sequent is correct if and
> only if there is a proof of $ψ$ with no undischarged assumptions.

Both $p$ and $\lnot p$ are not derivable without assumptions in a sound calculus, because $p$ is a propositional letter: it stands for a sentence whatever and thus we can always interpret it with a FALSE statement.

And the same for $\lnot p$.

Thus :

> $\nvdash p \text {  and  } \nvdash \lnot p$.

But the problem asks for : $\Gamma \vdash (\phi \lor \psi)$.

Consider the case : $\Gamma = \{ p \lor \lnot p \}$.

We have obviously :

> $p \lor \lnot p \vdash p \lor \lnot p $

but :

> > $p \lor \lnot p \nvdash p \text {  and  } p \lor \lnot p \nvdash \lnot p$.

---

"Real world" example : for sure, it is TRUE that "either it is raining or it is not raining".

But from the obvious fact that : it is the case that (it is raining or it is not raining) we cannot infer that it is raining, nor that it is not raining.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough I read an answer that I put up here a few years ago to a similar question, which also applies here.  I'm not sure where the answer lies though.

$\Gamma$ could be any set of formulas, correct?  So, suppose that $\Gamma$ is the set of all tautologies.  Now, can you fine some $\phi$ and some $\psi$ where Γ⊢(ϕ∨ψ) holds, but neither Γ⊢ϕ nor Γ⊢ψ?

Comment: Thanks Doug.  I suppose $\Gamma\vdash(\phi\lor\phi)$ would be an example of this.  But my real question has to do with Chiswell's hint: what's a simple sentence $p$ wherein $\vdash p$ and $\vdash(\neg p)$ are both incorrect sequents?

Comment: Γ⊢(ϕ∨ϕ) doesn't work when Γ is the set of all tautologies.  With respect to Chsiwell's hint, suppose that $\psi$ is $\lnot$p, and $\phi$ is p.