# Disproving: If $(\Gamma\vdash(\phi\,\lor\psi))$, either $(\Gamma\vdash\phi)$ or $(\Gamma\vdash\psi)$ is true

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In Chiswell's Mathematical Logic, there is the following problem is posed using the language of propositions (LP):

> In some systems of logic (mostly constructive systems where 'true' is taken to mean 'provable') there is a rule
>
> *if $(\Gamma\vdash(\phi\,\lor\psi))$ is a correct sequent then at least
>   one of $(\Gamma\vdash\phi)$ and $(\Gamma\vdash\psi)$ is also correct.*
>
> By giving a counterexample to a particular instance, show that this is
>   unacceptable as a rule for LP. [Start by giving counterexamples for
>   both the sequents $(\vdash p_0)$ and $(\vdash(\neg p_0))$.]

In my [first post on this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840017/when-is-both-a-statement-and-its-negation-incorrect), it was answered that one can let $\Gamma = \{p_0\,\lor\,(\neg p_0)\}$.  From there, one can deduce neither $(\Gamma\vdash p_0)$ nor $(\Gamma\vdash (\neg p_0))$.

But this does not proceed by the counterexample route that the author suggests.  Namely, he seems to imply that we should (1) take an *interpretation* of propositional variables $p_0,\,p_1,\,\ldots$ (setting each one equal to T or F), and (2) write $\phi$ and $\psi$ as functions of these propositional variables, and (3) pick sentences for $\Gamma$ which are all T, all with the conditions that (A) $(\phi\,\lor\psi)$ is evaluated as T, yet (B) **both $\phi$ and $\psi$ are evaluated as F**.

This, of course, seems impossible.  What, then, am I missing?  It seems that taking a concrete interpretation of the propositional symbols makes the constructivist's rule irrefutable.  (Note: this is supposed to be a very simple problem set, and I am an elementary logician).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion seems to stem from limiting yourself to considering only *one interpretation at a time*. Remember that "$A\vdash p$" means "**Every** interpretation in which $A$ is true, makes $p$ true." So to show $A\not\vdash p$, you just need to cook up a single interpretation in which $A$ is true and $p$ is false.

In particular, here you need to prove three things:

- $(1)\quad$ $\{p\vee\neg p\}\vdash p\vee\neg p$.
- $(2)\quad$ $\{p\vee\neg p\}\not\vdash p$.
- $(3)\quad$ $\{p\vee\neg p\}\not\vdash\neg p$.

The first point is easy. For the second and third points, you need to cook up counterexample interpretations, *but you don't need to use the same interpretation for each point!* That is:

- If you can find a single $\nu_1$ satisfying $p\vee\neg p$ but not satisfying $p$, you've done the second bulletpoint above.
- If you can find a single $\nu_2$ satisfying $p\vee\neg p$ but not satisfying $\neg p$, you've done the third bulletpoint above.

Nowhere is there a requirement that *both* bulletpoints be proved via the *same* counterexample. Indeed, the fact that points $(2)$ and $(3)$ above can't be proved by the same counterexample is *exactly what point $(1)$ says!*

Comment: Thanks Noah.  Is it fair to say that, "in any given interpretation, if (1) is true, then either (2) and (3) is true"?  Furthermore, can I say that, "for all interpretations, (1) being true neither implies that (2) is true nor (3) is true -- rather, which one of (2) or (3) being true will depend on the given interpretation".

Comment: @Doubt You're on the right track, but you're conflating various statements. Let me first rephrase your comment so that it's correct: "in any given interpretation, if $p\vee q$ is true, then either $p$ [or] $q$ is true." This is right. Similarly, "for all interpretations, $p\vee q$ being true neither implies that $p$ is true nor $q$ is true -- rather, which one of $p$ or $q$ [is] true will depend on the given interpretation" is correct in general. (cont'd)

Comment: However, note that my statements (1),(2),(3) are statements *about provability*; they're not statements which are true/false about a single interpretation, they're statements about *the class of all* interpretations. It doesn't make sense to ask whether "$\{p\vee q\}\vdash p$" (or similar) is true in an interpretation $\nu$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, you're last statement is very helpful!  The distinction between provability and truth is a evidently a very delicate one!  If you know of any (introductory-level) reading on this subject, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

See [Chiswell & Hodges, page 59](https://books.google.it/books?id=c4QSDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA59) :

> **Definition 3.4.7** Let ($Γ \vdash ψ$) be a sequent, and let $I$ be an interpretation that makes each propositional symbol appearing in formulas in the sequent into a meaningful sentence that is either true or false. Using this interpretation, each formula in the sequent is either true or false. We say that $I$ is a *counterexample* to the sequent if $I$ makes all the formulas of $Γ$ into true sentences and $ψ$ into a false sentence.

Consider the case : $\Gamma = \{ p \lor \lnot p \}$.

We have obviously that :

> $p \lor \lnot p \vdash p \lor \lnot p$

is *correct*, because there is no way to find an interpretation $I$ such that $I(p \lor \lnot p)$ is both TRUE (in order to satisfy the premise) and FALSE (in order to falsify the conclusion).

At the same time we have :

> > $p \lor \lnot p \nvdash p \text {  and  } p \lor \lnot p \nvdash \lnot p$.

The counterexample for the first one is $I_1$ such that $I_1(p)= \text {FALSE}$, while for the second one is an interpretation $I_2$ such that $I_2(p)= \text {TRUE}$.

We need a counterexample to show that a sequent is not correct. But there is no need that it is the same one for both sequents.

Comment: Thanks Mauro -- but this uses two different interpretations $v_1$ and $v_2$.  Aren't interpretations only meaningful if we stick to one of them?

Comment: @Doubt - we need a *counterexample* to show that the sequent is **not** correct; but it is not necessary that it is the same one for boty.

Comment: @Doubt Think about it this way: if I make two false claims, you don't have to refute them each in the same way. (To clarify, the false claims in this case are "$\{p\vee\neg p\}\vdash p$" and "$\{p\vee\neg p\}\vdash\neg p$" - **not** "$p$" and "$\neg p$.")